# Overlaying two plots with different dimensions using ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following reproducible working example:

```
library(scales)
library(tidyverse)

Canada <- c(383.927, 387.088, 390.648, 393.926, 395.947, 393.98, 388.772, 
392.391, 391.804, 389.321, 390.583, 390.062, 390.596, 392.19, 
392.267, 397.572, 397.807, 394.64, 391.737, 392.659, 392.483, 
392.012, 391.842, 394.06, 391.661, 390.621, 392.533, 396.218, 
401.802, 397.298, 392.468, 392.056, 394.752, 392.947, 392.606, 
391.839, 392.169, 393.29, 399.993, 396.114, 403.1, 398.263, 395.066, 
397.16, 399.562, 396.865, 392.898, 396.89, 398.529, 402.269, 
-9.999e+09, 398.294, 401.033, 399.328, -9.999e+09, 400.062, 395.829, 
397.754, 395.306, 394.87, 398.469, 399.91, 405.053, 404.678, 
402.185, 396.605, -9.999e+09, 402.252, 405.295, 401.08, 400.527, 
398.38, 400.152, 396.42, 402.497, 406.855, 403.56, -9.999e+09, 
-9.999e+09, 405.773, 402.306, 403.146, 403.079, 400.712)

x.axis <- c("Jan. 2010","","","","","July 2010","","","","","",
"Dec. 2010","","","","","","July 2011","","","","","",
"Dec. 2011","","","","","","July 2012","","","","","",
"Dec. 2012","","","","","","July 2013","","","","","",
"Dec. 2013","","","","","","July 2014","","","","","",
"Dec. 2014","","","","","","July 2015","","","","","",
"Dec. 2015","","","","","","July 2016","","","","","",
"Dec. 2016","")

Canplot <- ggplot() + geom_line(aes(time,Canada))
   + scale_x_continuous(breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 24))
   + theme_classic(base_size=12) + ylab("CO2 (ppm)") + xlab("Time") + ylim(380,410)
   + scale_x_discrete(limits = x.axis)
   + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust=1))

Canada1 <- c(390.704083333333, 393.322083333333, 393.900083333333, 396.780833333333, 
398.3274, 401.312181818182, 402.45) # The second set of data
```

Which produces this image:

[image]

`Canada` is an array of monthly CO2 and `Canada1` is an array of annual CO2. `Canplot` currently plots `Canada` and I want to overlay `Canada1` over it but I am not sure how to peg `Canada1` to different x axis values that line up with `July, (year)`. My initial thoughts were to either do `Canplot + geom_line() etc.`, I was wondering if this is the right way to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the same time labels for each of the datasets and then they can be plotted together using geom_line.

```
library(scales)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

Canada <- c(383.927, 387.088, 390.648, 393.926, 395.947, 393.98, 388.772, 
            392.391, 391.804, 389.321, 390.583, 390.062, 390.596, 392.19, 
            392.267, 397.572, 397.807, 394.64, 391.737, 392.659, 392.483, 
            392.012, 391.842, 394.06, 391.661, 390.621, 392.533, 396.218, 
            401.802, 397.298, 392.468, 392.056, 394.752, 392.947, 392.606, 
            391.839, 392.169, 393.29, 399.993, 396.114, 403.1, 398.263, 395.066, 
            397.16, 399.562, 396.865, 392.898, 396.89, 398.529, 402.269, 
            -9.999e+09, 398.294, 401.033, 399.328, -9.999e+09, 400.062, 395.829, 
            397.754, 395.306, 394.87, 398.469, 399.91, 405.053, 404.678, 
            402.185, 396.605, -9.999e+09, 402.252, 405.295, 401.08, 400.527, 
            398.38, 400.152, 396.42, 402.497, 406.855, 403.56, -9.999e+09, 
            -9.999e+09, 405.773, 402.306, 403.146, 403.079, 400.712)

time <- c("Jan. 2010","","","","","July 2010","","","","","",
            "Dec. 2010","","","","","","July 2011","","","","","",
            "Dec. 2011","","","","","","July 2012","","","","","",
            "Dec. 2012","","","","","","July 2013","","","","","",
            "Dec. 2013","","","","","","July 2014","","","","","",
            "Dec. 2014","","","","","","July 2015","","","","","",
            "Dec. 2015","","","","","","July 2016","","","","","",
            "Dec. 2016")

Canada1 <- c(390.704083333333, 393.322083333333, 393.900083333333, 396.780833333333, 
             398.3274, 401.312181818182, 402.45) # The second set of data
```

Here all of the months are listed out and a dataframe storing all the months, CO2 values and the labels that you want are kept.

```
## Set the date range and select by month
d1 <- as.Date(paste0("201001","01"), "%Y%m%d")
d2 <- as.Date(paste0("201612","01"), "%Y%m%d")

date1 <- format(seq(d1,d2,by="month"), "%Y%m%d")
dat <- data.frame(co2 = Canada, labels = as.character(time), date = date1, group = 1)

## Set the date range and select by year
d1 <- as.Date(paste0("201006","01"), "%Y%m%d")
d2 <- as.Date(paste0("201606","01"), "%Y%m%d")
date2 <- format(seq(d1,d2,by="year"), "%Y%m%d")

dat2 <- data.frame(co2 = Canada1, date = date2, group = 2)
```

The 2 datasets are plotted and the x labels are set to `dat$labels`

```
Canplot <- ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data = dat, aes(x = date, y = co2, group = group)) + 
  geom_line(data = dat2, aes(x = date, y = co2, group = group), color = "Red") + 
  ylim(380,410) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = data$labels)+
  theme_classic(base_size=12) + ylab("CO2 (ppm)") + xlab("Time") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust=1))

Canplot
```